# how do i loop through a directory and rename certain kind of files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following command to move files, but I want to rename some files through the same directory with filename like ***.csv.csv**  how to write the code?

```
FOR /R "C:\Share\PRC Interface" %%G IN (*_IP_*.csv) DO move "%%G" C:\ERP_Interface\PRCERP\IP
```

Comment: Please provide more written details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rename all `*.csv` files in a tree to `*.txt`

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*.csv) do ren "%%a" "%%~na.txt"
```

Comment: what si teh differences of %%a and %%G?i tried %%G it also work

Comment: You can use almost any character - and it is case sensitive within the for term.

Answer (score 0):

In shell you can write a code like,

```
dir=<your dir>

for file in `find $dir -name "*.csv.csv"` <or your search criteria>
do

filename=`echo $file|cut -f1 -d "."`  <will extract abc from abc.csv>
mv $file $filename.bad   <any extension you want to give> 

done
```